# Finding distance between skeleton and boundary using openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, euclidean-distance

I am trying to find maximum width of a curve using openCV in python. I used canny edge detector to get the boundaries of the curve. I have then managed to create a skeleton between them as shown by the red line in the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBOsv.jpg). I now need to find distance between this skeleton and the white line segments so that i can multiply the max distance by 2 to get the width. In short, i need the length of the blue line.

I tried using distance transform but i do not have a closed contour so i am getting incorrect width. I also tried dilation followed by erosion to get a closed contour but that changes the width of my curve. Stuck on this for a long time. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For each red pixel search for the nearest white pixel (which should be connected by the orthogonal line you are looking for) and calculate the distance using the Euclidean distance. You could then either take the average of all distances or min/max depending on your desired results.

Comment: imho there is no problem with distance transform in your case. Except that distances might be wrong with an error depending on the maximum size of the gaps in the contour.

Comment: @TA, how do i search for the nearest white pixel for each red pixel ? Can you please explain the logic ? I think this might work !

Comment: @Eshant As a straightforward approach: Search in the 8-neighboorhood of your pixel, then expand the size of your search environment subsequently until you get a hit.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum width is the maximal distance of any point on the boundary to the mid-line (multiplied by two perhaps).

To determine this value, you can use the `distance_transform` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Generate test image
size = (100, 100)

mid_line = np.zeros(size, dtype='uint8')
mid_line[(range(10, 40), range(10, 40))] = 1
mid_line[(range(40, 80), np.linspace(40, 70, 40).astype(int))] = 1

outline = np.zeros(size, dtype='uint8')
outline[(np.linspace(5, 33, 30).astype(int),
         np.linspace(16, 47, 30).astype(int))] = 1

outline[(np.linspace(14, 47, 30).astype(int),
         np.linspace(5, 35, 30).astype(int))] = 1

outline[(np.linspace(36, 72, 40).astype(int),
         np.linspace(50, 77, 40).astype(int))] = 1

outline[(np.linspace(47, 88, 40).astype(int),
         np.linspace(35, 65, 40).astype(int))] = 1

dist = cv2.distanceTransform(255 - (255*mid_line), cv2.DIST_L2, 3)

# Visualize
plt.figure("Mid line plus edges over the distance transform")
plt.imshow(dist, cmap='gray')
overlay = mid_line + 2 * outline
plt.imshow(np.ma.masked_where(overlay == 0, overlay), cmap='jet', alpha=0.6)

# Get the maximum width
max_width = np.max(dist[outline > 0])
print("Maximum width:", max_width)


plt.show()
```

which generates the image:

[image]

And outputs:

```
Maximum width: 10.954346
```

to the terminal.

Comment: works fine for the test image. But when i use it for my own image, i get the error : "sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32". Do you know what could be wrong ?

Comment: Could you update your question showing the code you tried?